# RoundCube sauserprefs plugin shows empty page

Tags: spamassassin, graphical-user-interface, roundcube

CentOS 7. Just installed the [sauserprefs](https://plugins.roundcube.net/packages/johndoh/sauserprefs) (version 1.17.1) plugin for [Roundcube](https://roundcube.net/) (version 1.3.8). The "Spam" tab is added OK. When I click on "Spam" tab, a page opens, where I can see the menu on the left side ("Section"), but nothing on the right side. When I try to click on the sections, I see that "General Settings" and "Bayes Settings" are causing the empty page on the right, other sections show some settings.

How do I fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sauserprefs version 1.17.1 you have to specify `sauserprefs_score_inc` parameter in sauserprefs `config.inc.php`:

https://github.com/johndoh/roundcube-sauserprefs/issues/52

https://github.com/johndoh/roundcube-sauserprefs/issues/48